# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://iot.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Internet of Things has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Ghanima]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://iot.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4657117182033920).

Comment: A big thank you to @MatsK for their willingness to serve the community, and congratulations @Ghanima!!  Looking forward to working with you!

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0a yes... it's a beta site, so it's an appointment.

Comment: Thanks at y'all and thanks @MatsK for stepping up!

Comment: Welcome to the mod team :)

Comment: @Ghanima I wish you good luck in your new appointment.

Comment: @MatsK Thank you and please rest assured that your contribution to community moderation is much appreciated.